# How can I write a query for the following scenario?

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks like this - http://d.pr/jQ1P and then another table (let's call it "actions" table) that contains a list of things that all users have done.

How can I write a query that can give me a count of how many new users referrer_id "1" has referred that also has at least 1 entry in the "actions" table?  Eg. For referrer_id "1", "1723" and "1724" both have at least 1 row in the "actions" table, but not "1725. So for user "1", he has successfully referred 2 users, even though there's also "1725".

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: It would be easier to understand your question if you added schema right into it. You can get table definition by running `explain actions` or `show create table actions`. And do the same for the other table.

Comment: Here is "actions" - http://d.pr/BHne, and here is "referral" - http://d.pr/V2Ei.

Comment: Doesn't @Corbin's solution work for you?

Comment: what's not right? Seems ok to me. Do you have a sample data dump that I can play with?

Comment: Sure - here is data dump for "actions" - http://d.pr/vDV3 and here's data dump for "referral" - http://d.pr/XWkn.  The correct query should show that the referred count for referred_id "1" is 2 and for referred_id "3" is 1.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5952/discussion-between-koes-bong-and-sergei-tulentsev)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT r.new_user_id)  
FROM
  referral r    
  JOIN actions a ON a.fk_userid = r.new_user_id 
WHERE 
  r.referrer_id = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a JOIN, you know that if there is a row, then at least 1 row matched in the JOIN table.  You can combine that with a GROUP BY to pull unique ids.  I have a feeling this could be a in a much more efficient way, but the first thing that comes to mind is:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(referrals.new_user_id) 
FROM 
    referrals
    JOIN actions ON actions.user_id = referrals.new_user_id 
WHERE 
    referrals.referrer_id = 1
GROUP BY referrals.new_user_id;
```

Edit:  After thinking about it for a bit, assuming everything is indexed, I can't think of a more efficient solution.  Some mild googling suggests that COUNT(DISTINCT referrals.new_user_id) might be faster instead of using the GROUP BY.